# comma separated list invalid near.. with comma_to_table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to take a comma delimited string and insert each value as a new row into a table.  I have taken the below example from Lalit Kumar B and modified the data to resemble what my data will look like.

```
DECLARE
    L_INPUT VARCHAR2(4000) := '522,33-23,125,658,25,12-500';
    L_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER;
    L_ARRAY DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
BEGIN
    DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(L_INPUT, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => L_ARRAY);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_COUNT);
    FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Element ' || TO_CHAR(I) || ' of array contains: ' || SUBSTR(L_ARRAY(I), 2));
        INSERT INTO TEST22 VALUES
        (SUBSTR(L_ARRAY(I), 2)
        );
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I am receiving the following oracle error: ORA-20001: comma-separated list invalid near 33-23

What can i do to handle data of the form "33-23"?  If I take the '-' out of my data the above will run as desired.  This is not ideal as some of my data will have '-' in it and it cannot be removed.

Comment: What do you think the procedure `dbms_utility.comma_to_table` does? It is meant to work with database identifiers (in the format `schema.table.column@link` and its variations). Now, you MAY abuse it to just split comma-separated strings, as you are trying - with unpredictable results. Dashes are not allowed in identifiers. In any case, if what you need is to split a comma-delimited string, say so; there are ways, but the `comma_to_table` procedure is not one of them.

Comment: replace them with an underscore

Comment: Wait... is Lalit showing this as a method for splitting strings? Or is he using it for something else? If he is showing it for splitting strings, please provide a link; he should remove this method from the list of valid methods.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I cannot modify the data.  The data represents what my real data could look like and as such i cannot modify the data, simply to insert it.

Comment: @mathguy Yes Lalit was showing this as a way to "insert comma separated string values into table" which is exactly what i need to do.  Here is the link.. https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/oracle-insert-comma-seperated-string-values-into-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use CONNECT BY to effectively loop through the string elements. If you run just the query you'll see how this works. The regular expression allows for NULL list elements should they occur.

```
insert into TEST(col_a) 
select regexp_substr('522,33-23,125,658,25,12-500', '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('522,33-23,125,658,25,12-500', ',')+1
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  This is what I needed.  I had to modify a little as I had a larger insert list, but this is what I was looking for.  Again thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE. It has some bugs with numeric strings. I tried some methods and finally write this function instead of it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE UTILITY_METHODS IS

TYPE STRING_TAB IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(512) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(  P_STRING        IN VARCHAR2
                   , P_SEPRATOR_CHAR IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN STRING_TAB;

END UTILITY_METHODS;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY UTILITY_METHODS IS

FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(  P_STRING        IN VARCHAR2
                   , P_SEPRATOR_CHAR IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN STRING_TAB
IS
  STR_TAB STRING_TAB;
  L_SEP_CHAR VARCHAR2(1) := NVL(P_SEPRATOR_CHAR, ',');
  L_PATERN VARCHAR2(10)  := '[^' || L_SEP_CHAR || ']+';
BEGIN
  IF P_STRING IS NULL THEN
    RETURN STR_TAB;
  END IF;

  FOR RC IN (
              WITH L_LINE(STR) AS    
              (
                SELECT P_STRING
                FROM DUAL
              )
              SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, L_PATERN, 1, LEVEL) SP_STR
              FROM L_LINE
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(STR, L_SEP_CHAR) + 1
            )
  LOOP
    STR_TAB(STR_TAB.COUNT) := RC.SP_STR;  
  END LOOP;

  RETURN STR_TAB;
END;  

END UTILITY_METHODS;
```

If you want use this function in a select statement you can change the return type of function to PIPE_LINED.